# how to manipulate the keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-softkeyboard

I want to manipulate the keyboard in iphone .
basically want to create the action on the keyboard.

thanks advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, create additional, non-standard button on the keyboard?
Try [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html)